# Kindle Fire and Youtube Links in WebView

Tags: android, youtube

We have several apps in the Android Market that we also submitted to Amazon to their Appstore for Android.  Things worked well until the Kindle Fire came out.  In several of our apps, we launch Youtube videos from a link on a WebView.  Here is the relevant code from setOnClickListener that pushes the view and handles the Youtube links:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient (new WebViewClient () {
     @ Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("vnd.youtube")){  
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
         } else{
            return false;
         }
     }
});
```

As I said, this works great on all Android devices that we've tested on, but we are getting notified from Amazon that they are getting crashes when clicking on the video links.  I assume this is happening because the Fire does not come loaded with an YouTube app.  Has anyone else experienced similar issues?  What would be the prefered method for playing a youtube video from a webview on the Fire?

Here is the logcat supplied by Amazon:

```
01-09 12:28:32.715 W/dalvikvm(5805): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-09 12:28:32.715 D/ActivityManager(1372): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=vnd.youtube://XXXXXXXXXX } from pid 5805
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=vnd.youtube://XXXXXXXXXX }
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromChild(Activity.java:3103)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2883)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2969)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at com.XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX.VideoActivity$1$1.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(VideoActivity.java)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:216)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:323)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:850)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
01-09 12:28:32.793 E/AndroidRuntime(5805):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**Edit**

I was able to get this working properly now.  Basically, I copied my video folder (which contains all of the html for the video pages) in assets to a new video_fire directory.  I updated the actual code to point to the video_fire directory if the android.os.Build.MODEL is "Kindle Fire" and to the normal video directory for all else. I also modified the webview allocation to use getParent() rather than VideoActivity.this.  This fixed the issue I described in the comments about full screen displays. Below is the updated code that I used (when clicking on an item in a ListView it displays the appropriate html page):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    String contentsOfHtml;
    try {
        if (android.os.Build.MODEL.equals("Kindle Fire")) {
            contentsOfHtml = readFileAsString("video_fire/"+htmlarray[position]);
        } else {
            contentsOfHtml = readFileAsString("video/"+htmlarray[position]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        // Should never happen! 
        throw new RuntimeException(e); 
    } 
    WebView mWebView =  new WebView(getParent());
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings(); 
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient (new WebViewClient () {
        @ Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("vnd.youtube")){  
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
         } else{
            return false;
         }
        }
    });
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", contentsOfHtml, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
ReflectionGroup.group.replaceView(mWebView);
return;
});
```

Yes, I'm using ActivityGroup which is depreciated (this is old code).  I'm working on updating the base code that this uses to implement Fragments...

I then have html for normal devices:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <p class="title">Title</p>
    <hr/>
    <a href="vnd.youtube://XXXXX"><div><center><img src="images/video1.jpg" width="220" height="150"></center></div></a>
    </center>
    <p class="para">Text</p>
    <hr/>       
</body>
</html>
```

And specific HTML for Kindle Fire.  I suppose I should check to see if this code would work on other devices, too, but that will have to be put on my to-do list.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <p class="title">Title</p>
    <hr/>
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="600" height="361" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXX" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
    </center>
    <p class="para">Text    </p>
    <hr/>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just bought a kindle fire today and I'm working on testing it.  I've got the video to play using a standard iframe, but when playing the video, if I click on the full screen button in the frame, it force closes: 01-23 21:58:27.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2485): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@405315a8 is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: editted my answer. You should also update your question adding this new problem to it, so that one can see it agaion in the list and answer it

Comment: @WookieLNX if it says "unable to add window" then you probably have something wrong in your code potentially.

Comment: he has said that error states "is your activity running". This clearly means that he is modifying a view that he created in that activity and  is manipulating after the activity has finished.

Comment: What about using the mobile link instead of the normal youtube link? http://m.youtube.com/... instead of http://www.youtube.... ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to catch this exception with the specific exception type and then write the code to launch a browser by editting your url (start it with "http", else it wont be open in web browser).
*`....
catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){

url = YOUR_URL_STARTING_WITH_HTTP;
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
}`*

**Editted Section:**

now thats a different problem, generally comes if the view is called or tried to show/modify after the activity is finished. Are you doing something in onPostExecuted() related to ui in any of the async task ?? This might be happening after the activity created that task is finished.

Comment: What is the point of doing that .. if its doing the exact same thing he tried?

Answer (score 1):

if there is nothing that can handle the youtube links. Then you already have a problem.

This error clearly states:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=vnd.youtube://XXXXXXXXXX }
```

Meaning nothing in the system can handle that, I dont think you did anything wrong, but then again i'm not familiar with the platform of the kindle fire. however; with some utilization of the PackageManager, you can figure it out.

Comment: Kindle Fire does not ship with a YouTube App, whereas almost all Android devices have it installed by default. In fact, there is no official YouTube app available in the Amazon Appstore.  I think there is some bad blood between Amazon and Google preventing it from being there...

Comment: If this is infact the case, then you will have to depend on the browser to render the youtube links which will possibly take it out of your hands unless you modify the webview as its being run.

Comment: You can look at my solution above.  So far it works well since I'm just embedding the video in a webview.